# What would cause Citrix to disallow additional .EXEs to be spawned by a published application?

Tags: citrix

### Problem

We have a number of clients utilizing Citrix for various pieces software we help them support and recently had a new one come online using Citrix, but they're having issues with certain functions of one of the programs when accessed through their published application.

The program runs as one .exe/window, but additional utilities/exes launch and run in additional windows when requested by the parent EXE. The utility spawns an additional process on the application server, which won't come through to the end user in the current configuration.

While supporting this program in various other Citrix environments we haven't encountered this issue, so i'm hoping the brain trust here at serverfault can provide a cause and solution.

### Attempts at Troubleshooting

I logged into the database server for the program in question and wasn't able to recreate the issue. I also logged into the desktop of the Citrix server and ran it there to confirm it works. It seems the breaking point is between the Citrix server and the published application for the end-user.

I did some searching around and found this:
http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/284563-how-to-run-2-or-more-executables-under-one-citrix-ica-session/

I was about to recommend it to the on-site folks supporting the Citrix servers, but the last post makes it seem as though it isn't an ideal solution to this problem.

I also did a search here using various phrasing and didn't come up with anything helpful.

### TL;DR

How can I make Citrix show the end-user any child window/process spawned by my parent window/process?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a good solution for this?  I've got a similar situation.

Comment: The client figured it out, but I wasn't able to get details on what they did. Strangely enough, I have another client dealing with the same thing as of a few days ago, and came back to check if this ever got an answer.